# Convert DateTime claim to string in Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I had a look at the below Date transforms documented but couldnt find one which converts datetime to string. How would you achieve this in the custom policy?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/date-transformations

Reason is AssertDateTimeIsGreaterThan takes input claims as string type. I want to pass currentDateTime to this transform! However as the currentDateTime is of type datetime, it fails!

Regards,
Dipesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/date-transformations#datetimecomparison

Then assert the Boolean
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue

This allows you to work with dateTime and Boolean to perform the comparison and assertion.

Comment: Neat @JasSuri. This is a common question that I get. It would be useful to have two Transform methods - DateTime to string and vice versa. I have one customer that passes a date in the query string so I have to transform it using a REST API.

Comment: Thats great Jas! Thanks and that will do for now but really need transforms for DT to string and vice versa as pointed out by @rbrayb!